# Solve $4 A (L^{3/4}) - wL (((24 - L) w)^{-3/4}) = -(((24 - L) w)^{1/4})$ for L? Using Mathematica

Tags: problem-solving, math-software, mathematica

I'm trying to solve

$$4 A (L^{3/4}) - wL (((24 - L) w)^{-3/4}) = -(((24 - L) w)^{1/4})$$

for $L$ using Mathematica, and it spits the following out:

```
Solve[4 A (L^(3/4)) - 
    wL (((24 - L) w)^(-3/4)) = -(((24 - L) w)^(1/4)), L]
Set::write: Tag Plus in 4 A L^(3/4)-wL/((24-L) w)^(3/4) is Protected. >>
Solve::naqs: ((24-L) w)^(1/4) is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. >>
```

What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It  means that you cannot assign a value to an expression. Your error is in using assignment `=` instead of a comparison `==`.

Comment: The code has also a second error: `wL` should be `w L`.

Answer (score 0):

Never use upper-case letters to begin a variable name as it may conflict with the internal names within *Mathematica*.

```
Clear[a, l, w];
Simplify@Solve[
  4 a (l^(3/4)) - w l (((24 - l) w)^(-3/4)) == -(((24 - l) w)^(1/4)), 
  l]
```

$\left\{\left\{l\to \frac{1}{12} \left(144-\sqrt{3} \sqrt{\frac{\left(w-13824 a^4\right)
   w}{a^4 \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^{12}
   \left(15552 a^4-w\right) w^2}}}-\frac{w}{a^4}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2
   a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right)
   w^2}}}{a^4}+6912}\right)\right\},\left\{l\to \frac{1}{12} \left(\sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{\frac{\left(w-13824 a^4\right) w}{a^4 \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2
   a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right)
   w^2}}}-\frac{w}{a^4}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right) w^2}}}{a^4}+6912}+144\right)\right\},\left\{l\to
   \frac{1}{24} \left(288-\sqrt{6} \sqrt{\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(13824
   a^4-w\right) w}{a^4 \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right) w^2}}}-\frac{2 w}{a^4}+\frac{i
   \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right) w^2}}}{a^4}+13824}\right)\right\},\left\{l\to
   \frac{1}{24} \left(\sqrt{6} \sqrt{\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(13824
   a^4-w\right) w}{a^4 \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right) w^2}}}-\frac{2 w}{a^4}+\frac{i
   \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3}
   \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right)
   w^2}}}{a^4}+13824}+288\right)\right\},\left\{l\to \frac{1}{24} \left(288-\sqrt{6}
   \sqrt{\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(13824 a^4-w\right) w}{a^4
   \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552
   a^4-w\right) w^2}}}-\frac{2 w}{a^4}-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-71663616
   w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right)
   w^2}}}{a^4}+13824}\right)\right\},\left\{l\to \frac{1}{24} \left(\sqrt{6}
   \sqrt{\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \left(13824 a^4-w\right) w}{a^4
   \sqrt[3]{-71663616 w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552
   a^4-w\right) w^2}}}-\frac{2 w}{a^4}-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-71663616
   w a^8+20736 w^2 a^4-w^3+331776 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{a^{12} \left(15552 a^4-w\right)
   w^2}}}{a^4}+13824}+288\right)\right\}\right\}$

Comment: And don't use l because it looks like 1.